# PHP photo else/if picking

Tags: php

Hello there im having little problem with else if i can't figure out the 'else if' i want to make it if the

```
$photo = 'http://www.localhost/uploads/'.$usersInfo['image_id'].'.jpg';
$photoModeImage = 'http://www.localhost/uploads/thumbs/'.$usersInfo['image_id'].'.jpg';
```

goes wrong then else if should pick the photos

```
<?php
require_once '../../../common/server/php/settings.php';



//Connect to users database
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','123456') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('registracija',$db) or die(mysql_error());

//Init request parameters
$userName = (isset($_REQUEST["user_name"])) ? urldecode($_REQUEST["user_name"]) : "";
$password = (isset($_REQUEST["password"])) ? urldecode($_REQUEST["password"]) : "";
$uid = (isset($_REQUEST["uid"])) ? urldecode($_REQUEST["uid"]) : "";
$pwdmd5 = md5($password);

//Check if user filled login and password in the login screen (Chat authorization)
if($userName != "" && $password != "")
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$userName."' AND password='".$pwdmd5."'";
}
//session/cookie base authorization (Auto login)
else if ($_SESSION['user_id']!="")
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Profile_id='".$_SESSION["user_id"]."'";
}
// Non session/cookie based autologin authorization
else if ($uid!="")
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$_GET['uid']."'";
}
else
{
  echo '<auth error="AUTH_ERROR" />';
  exit;
}

//Select user data
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
{
  //User found. get user info
  $usersInfo = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if($userInfo['image_id'] ==''){
    $photo = FLASHCOMS_HTTP_ROOT.'common/images/User1_120.png';
    $photoModeImage = FLASHCOMS_HTTP_ROOT.'common/images/User1_40.png';  
  }
  else{
    $photo = 'http://127.0.0.1:8082/uploads/'.$usersInfo['image_id'].'.jpg';
    $photoModeImage = 'http://127.0.0.1:8082/uploads/thumbs/'.$usersInfo['image_id'].'.jpg';
  }
  $answer = '<auth>';
  $answer .= '<userName><![CDATA['.$userName.']]></userName>';
  $answer .= '<gender>male</gender>';
  $answer .= '<age>'.$userInfo['age'].'</age>';
  $answer .= '<level>regular</level>';
  $answer .= '<photo><![CDATA['.$photo.']]></photo>';
  $answer .= '<photoModeImage><![CDATA['.$photoModeImage.']]></photoModeImage>';
  $answer .= '</auth>';
  echo $answer;
  exit;
}
else 
{
  //User not found OR authorization failed
  echo '<auth error="AUTH_ERROR" />';
  exit;
}

?>
```

what i need to make it work is

```
else if ($photo['$image_id']!='')
    {

    $photo = FLASHCOMS_HTTP_ROOT.'common/images/no_photo.png';
    $photoModeImage = FLASHCOMS_HTTP_ROOT.'common/images/no_photo.png';
```

but images are not showing.

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `users`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `age` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `confirmcode` varchar(32) default NULL,
  `gender` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `about_me` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `image_id` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_user`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of users
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('1', '', 'localhost@myemail.com', '', 'Mentro', '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99', 'y', '', '', '', '', '1');
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What does `$photo` and `$photoModeImage` return?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Show `no_photo.png` if there's no photo for a user?

Comment: remove the `exit` and see if it works

Comment: I don't think that removing exit will help here. Seems that the output format is text/xml. Looks like this is something like api call. I'm not sure though

Comment: yeah im trying to set no_photo.png well the $photo is showing in profile page the $photomode is thumb image showing little icon on the chat

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to set `no_photo.png` for users who don't have their userpics. If i'm right then do the next:

1) Make sure that `FLASHCOMS_HTTP_ROOT.'common/images/no_photo.png'` is exists.

2) 
Change it to this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
{
  //User found. get user info
  $usersInfo = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if($userInfo['image_id'] ==''){
    $photo = FLASHCOMS_HTTP_ROOT.'common/images/User1_120.png';
    $photoModeImage = FLASHCOMS_HTTP_ROOT.'common/images/User1_40.png';    
  }
  else{
    $photo = 'http://127.0.0.1:8082/uploads/'.$usersInfo['image_id'].'.jpg';
    $photoModeImage = 'http://127.0.0.1:8082/uploads/thumbs/'.$usersInfo['image_id'].'.jpg';
  }
  $answer = '<auth>';
  $answer .= '<userName><![CDATA['.$userName.']]></userName>';
  $answer .= '<gender>male</gender>';
  $answer .= '<age>'.$userInfo['age'].'</age>';
  $answer .= '<level>regular</level>';
  $answer .= '<photo><![CDATA['.$photo.']]></photo>';
  $answer .= '<photoModeImage><![CDATA['.$photoModeImage.']]></photoModeImage>';
  $answer .= '</auth>';
  echo $answer;
  exit;
}
else 
{
  //User not found OR authorization failed
  echo '<auth error="AUTH_ERROR" />';
  exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: yes im trying to set no_photos.png but now it showing only the no_photo.png even if user have photo

Comment: can you do `print_r($userInfo);` after `$usersInfo = mysql_fetch_array($result);` and show the results?

Comment: same hmm if i change 

if($userInfo['image_id'] =='') to if($userInfo['image_id'] =='0') 

then it shows profile photo but if i change image_id in mysql table it dosn't show the no_photo.png

Comment: I think that the problem is with the data in the table. if you could also show me what you have in `registracija` table, and what credentials you're entering to check the user's icon.. it will probably help me to understand what's wrong.

Comment: it looks fine. make sure that you have http://127.0.0.1:8082/uploads/1.jpg and http://127.0.0.1:8082/uploads/thumbs/'.$usersInfo['image_id'].'.jpg at the server. I hope this is your local test server. at least I dont recommend you to use absolute paths here as if you upload your script somewhere 'http://127.0.0.1:8082/' will not work for other users.

Comment: yes im using local test sever thats why im testing to make it sure its gona work before i post to vps server ill try on vps server thx for helping

Comment: i wish i don't have enough reputation :)